# How to spinup localstack in CI/CD

Tags: localstack

I am able to create and test AWS locally using localstack. So, I'm wondering if there are any use cases out there where I can reference how to add localstack in ci/cd and run your test cases? any pointer showing the sample would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check the LocalStack [doc](https://docs.localstack.cloud/ci/github-actions/) on using LocalStack in GitHub Actions. Let us know if something is not working there.

Answer (score 12):

With a bit of work I [managed to get LocalStack](https://github.com/codetalkio/patterns-serverless-rust-minimal/blob/3fdc88c2d92724005ca4bf875bbbdc36639c216f/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L102-L160) working correctly in my CI.

A minimal example using GitHub Actions:

```
name: ci

on: push

jobs:
  localstack:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      localstack:
        image: localstack/localstack:latest
        env:
          SERVICES: cloudformation,iam,sts,ssm,s3,cloudwatch,cloudwatch-logs,lambda,dynamodb,apigateway
          DEFAULT_REGION: eu-west-1
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: localkey
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: localsecret
        ports:
          - 4566:4566
          - 4571:4571
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Deploying to LocalStack
        run: |
          # Your deployment code...
        env:
          DEFAULT_REGION: eu-west-1
          AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: "000000000000"
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: localkey
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: localsecret
```

You can tweak the `SERVICES` and `DEFAULT_REGION` a bit. The `Deploying to LocalStack` step contains the environment variables necessary for the deployment to go smoothly.

You would fill in the rest of the steps here depending on what you are doing in your CI.

---

You can checkout https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions for some more information on the syntax in the GitHub Actions workflow files.

Comment: This answer is good, just a bit excessive: 1) You do not need the list of `SERVICES`, as LocalStack now loads them the moment they are being used.
2) `DEFAULT_REGION` is long deprecated, LocalStack has a proper multi-region support now.
3) `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` do not mean anything with LocalStack.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which service you use you may also need to mount `docker.sock`, for example the LocalStack service in my GitHub action is:

```yaml
    services:
      localstack:
        image: localstack/localstack:latest
        env:
          SERVICES: iam,lambda
        ports:
          - 4566:4566
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```